# Friction on a rolling ball

Tags: physics

How long will a ball, say a billiard ball, stop rolling on a flat surface for a given coefficient of friction? What is the formula for the ball's decreasing velocity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Time to stop is  initial_speed/(mu * g)
```

Derivation below.

Assume the ball is moving to the right, then the free body diagram is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The equation of motion is $$ m\ddot{x} = -\mu N $$
But \$ N = mg \$ hence $$ \ddot{x} = -\mu g $$
Using the constant acceleration kinematic equation
$$ \dot{x}_{final} = \dot{x}_{initial} + \ddot{x}t = \dot{x}_{initial} - \mu gt$$
Then, by letting final speed be zero, we solve for the time for the ball to stop.
$$ t= \frac{\dot{x}_{initial}}{\mu g}$$
For example, using coefficient of friction \$ \mu = 0.15 \$, initial speed of \$ \dot{x} = 15 \$ meters per second and earth's gravity \$ g=9.81 \$, then the time to stop is
$$ t = \frac{15}{(0.15)(9.81)} = 10.2 s$$

Comment: Latex is not supported. Some of the stack exchange sites support MathJax, but GDSE is not currently one of them. There's a [meta post regarding adding MathJax support to GDSE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/can-we-enable-mathjax-on-gdse-revisited). If it would have helped your question, vote accordingly.